# combine two lists and map to new class object with rxjava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

Consider the following input : Calling network call will retrieve client object

```
data class Client(
val name: String,
val phoneNumber: String,
val frequentContacts: List<String>,
val allContacts: List<String>
)
```

what i need to do is to map similar names in frequentContacts and allContacts list in new object and subscribe on the output.

assume the response from network call will return this Client Object

```
{
"name": "Jack",
"phoneNumber": "90284302424",
"frequentContacts": [
    "John",
    "Sam"
    ],
"allContacts": [
    "John",
    "Adam",
    "Peter",
    "Kim",
    "Sam"
    ]
}
```

what i need receive in subscribe newly create object .

```
data class clientViewModel(val name: String,val isFrequent: Boolean)
```

so in onSuccess i should have instance from clientViewModel

Expected output :

("John", true")

("Adam", false")

("Peter", false")

("Kim", false")

("Sam", true")

here what i am up to

```
clientRepository.getClientById(clientId)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doAfterTerminate { view.hideProgress() }
.flatMap{it.frequentContacts}
.subscribe{
onSuccess(item: ClientViewModel){}
onError(){}
onFinish(){}
}
```

but this not work because once i used flat map i lose the allContacts list
any help ?

I read about GroupBy operator but i am using Single...

Comment: What do you think of:

`.flatMap{it.allContacts.map{c->Pair(c,it.frequentContacts.contains(c))} }`

Comment: @Raphael i tried it shows me type miss match error 
Required :SingleSource <out(???)>
Found : List<Pair(String, Boolean)>

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'd just do this:

```
clientRepository.getClientById(clientId)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doFinally { view.hideProgress() }
.map { client ->
    client.allContacts.map { contact ->
        clientViewModel(name = contact, isFrequent = client.frequentContacts.contains(contact))
    }
}
.subscribeBy(onSuccess = { list: List<clientViewModel> -> 
    ...
}, onError = { err -> ... })
```